# What is minimal model, unitary, rational, and irrational CFT?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

**Minimal model**
In Francesco conformal field theory page 210 only
$$
c=1-\frac{6}{p(p+1)}
$$
was the representation without the nonunitary representation.

However, for the theory to be unitary, [it only required that $|p-q|=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(physics)#Representations) where
$$
c=1-\frac{6(p-q)^2}{pq}
$$

On the other reference (such as Francesco section 8), the condition was changed to $(p,q)$ to be coprimes different from the previous conditions, i.e. $|3-5|=2$ were co primes.

Does the unitary minimal model require $p=p+1$, $|p-q|=1$, or just $gcd(p,q)=1$($p,q$ were coprimes)?

---

**Rational CFT**
The definition of rational CFT was rather confusing. There's were many references saying the different definitions:

1. $c$ to be a rational number.
2. the representation of CFT have finite primaries.
3. in the closed boson theory, the radius $R$ to be rational multiple of the self dual raduis $R_{self}$.

The 2 and 3 were consistent. However, for 1 it was unclear. For example, inverting the expression of the central charge, it was not necessary that
$$
(p-q)^2=\frac{(1-c) pq}{6}
$$
to have integer solutions for any rational number $c\in (0,1)$.

What was the definition of Rational CFT? (the definition of irrational CFT could be resolved at once) Especially, how was the "trace anomaly" $c$ connected to the multiple $b$ of the self dual radius $R=bR_{self}$?

---

**Unitary model**
Unitary model were the states without negative norm states.

a. Were all minimal model unitary? such as $(p=5,q=3)$? (because $|p-q|=2\neq 1$)

b. Is all rational theory necessary unitary? i.e. what if there was a $c$ that does not have integer solutions $p,q$?

Comment: 1. Please only ask a single question per post. 2. Why is this entire post written in the past tense? CFT or Francesco's book didn't suddenly stop existing, did they?

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. I will try to split them into several questions.(Mainly they were interconnected definitions, and it might look better if they were put into one page.) 2. (Making a joke)I don't know the answer to that question if I stopped looking at those books, or equivalently if there were to be better books and the world stopped reading them. It started as a "maker" to indicate the theorems that had been proven or something that had been thought, and then turned into a writing style.

Comment: The minimal models are only unitary when $|p-q|=1$. The definition of rationality is just your 2. Rational theories can be non-unitary, such as the minimal models with $|p-q|\neq 1$.

Comment: @MengCheng I saw Gaberdiel used that in one of his papers, but mostly the 1. and 3. were mentioned more frequently, and it made more sense of what the "rational" was. 2. might be more property called a theory with a finite representation.

Comment: Following from 2 one can show that the central charge and all conformal dimensions are rational numbers. 3 is only about free bosons.

Comment: @MengCheng But what about the inverse? Also, being a limiting case $c=1$ free boson was also rational, but it has "irrational cases" from the classifying algebra.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate One can perhaps prove that if there is a primary with irrational dimension, then there are infinitely many distinct primaries by taking powers, not sure whether this has been carefully done anywhere. You are probably right that the name "rational" does not reflect the actual definition in terms of finiteness condition, but that's an accepted definition in literature.

Comment: @MengCheng Thank you. However about the rational theory being non unitary, could you explain a little bit?(i.e. here in the minimal model page https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714612/whats-minimal-model). Because if a theory is not unitary, such as $(p=5,q=2)$ case, then the W algebra $(W_n)^*=W_{-n}$ was not necessarily true. I don't understand how a minimal model could be constructed or described in that case. Does $(L_{n})^*=L_{-n}$ still hold?

Comment: @MengCheng *I separated the question about the definition of the rational CFT as requested( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715438/what-is-rational-cft )