# What's minimal model?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

**Minimal model**
In Francesco conformal field theory page 210 only
$$
c=1-\frac{6}{p(p+1)}
$$
was the representation without the nonunitary representation.

However, for the theory to be unitary, [it only required that $|p-q|=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(physics)#Representations) where
$$
c=1-\frac{6(p-q)^2}{pq}
$$

On the other reference (such as Francesco section 8), the condition was changed to $(p,q)$ to be coprimes different from the previous conditions, i.e. $|3-5|=2$ were co primes.

---

Some times the term "rational" theory were used interchangeably for the theory with $c\in (0,1)$. However, inverting the expression of the central charge, it was not necessary that
$$
(p-q)^2=\frac{(1-c) pq}{6}
$$
to have integer solutions for any rational number $c\in (0,1)$. Does this mean rational theory with $c\in (0,1)$ included things other than minimal model?

---

Also, as mentioned above, the minimal model was introduced as the unitary model without negative norm states. However, the unitary model were proven for the $|p-q|=1$, but what about $(p=5,q=3)$, i.e. $|5-3|=2\neq 1$? Are they still unitary model or minimal model?

Does the unitary minimal model require $p=p+1$, $|p-q|=1$, or just $gcd(p,q)=1$($p,q$ were coprimes)? Is minimal model necessarily unitary?

Comment: "Minimal model" and "rational CFT" both mean there exists a chiral algebra X such that your theory only has finitely many operators which are primary with respect to X. If all currents can be made from the stress tensor, this is the special case of "Virasoro minimal model" or "Virasoro rational CFT" though in practice no one says the latter. This is the case where $c$ has to be $1 - 6(p-q)^2/pq$ for $p$ and $q$ coprime.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I don't know. For the theory to have a finite representation was a property. In the "what might be minimal model"( such as the ising model )it was proven to be the case, and for some CFT(with certain coefficients) were also proven. It didn't go the other way around.

Comment: I do know. The Virasoro primaries in the Ising model are not "finite representations" or even finite dimensional representations. But there are finitely many of them so the definition for X = Virasoro is fulfilled.

Comment: @ConnorBehan What did you mean? Ising model had three primary, each had a non truncating character(infinite decedents). The representation was finite.

Comment: This question makes me wonder what is not clear in the relevant Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(physics) . Or why people do not check Wikipedia before asking basic questions.

Comment: @SylvainRibault Because according to Wikipedia(the ones you provided was already in the OP), the "types of the model" is unitary "if and only if" $|p-q|=1$. That only explained the $A$ series minimal, and does that mean that there's many minimal model are not unitary? From the W-algebra perspective, that meant $(W_n)^*=W_{-n}$ would no longer necessarily be true. Then the entire CFT or even QFT language seemed to be useless at that point. The Wikipedia did not mention anything about that.

Comment: Yes, "most" minimal models are not unitary. The unitarity condition $|p-q|=1$ is valid for all three series A, D, E I believe. I do not see why you mention W-algebras: there also exist W-minimal models but all cited references and formulas are for Virasoro minimal models.