# What is rational CFT?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

The definition of [rational CFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_conformal_field_theory) was rather confusing. There's were many references saying the different definitions:

1. $c$ to be a rational number.
2. the representation of CFT have finite primaries. (This was the definition on the Wikipedia. It was also used in one of Gaberdiel's paper. But as Meng Cheng pointed out this does not actually mean the finiteness condition.)
3. in the closed boson theory, the radius $R$ to be rational multiple of the self dual raduis $R_{self}$.

The 2 and 3 were consistent. However, for 1 it was unclear. For example, inverting the expression of the central charge, it was not necessary that
$$
(p-q)^2=\frac{(1-c) pq}{6}
$$
to have integer solutions for any rational number $c\in (0,1)$.

What was the definition of Rational CFT? (the definition of irrational CFT could be resolved at once) How was the condition 2 translated into condition 1 and condition 3? Especially, how was the "trace anomaly" $c$ connected to the multiple $b$ of the self dual radius $R=bR_{self}$?

Comment: condition 1 is necessary but not sufficient. For example the compact boson has $c=1$ but it is generically non-rational. The correct condition is 2, namely there are finitely many primaries *with respect to a sufficiently large algebra* (which contains Virasoro, and generically other currents). A standard reference is https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-123/issue-3/The-operator-algebra-of-orbifold-models/cmp/1104178892.full

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/055032138890627X The appendix contains a discussion about three definitions of rationality. It does not contain the now standard one (i.e. finite number of primaries with respect to a certain chiral algebra).

Comment: The condition $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ has little to do with the notion of rationality in CFT. For rationality with respect to the Virasoro algebra, see again Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_conformal_field_theory Rationality depends on the algebra: the compactified free boson is irrational with respect to the affine $U(1)$ algebra for any radius, but under your condition 3 you can find a larger algebra with respect to which the theory is rational.